# Kotlin + SpringBootTest + Junit 5 + AutoConfigureMockMvc: test passing when it was supposed to fail (seems @BeforeEach not taking effect)

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit5, spring-test-mvc, springmockito

I coded a very simple and common CRUD in Kotlin. I want to do basic tests as testing post, delete, get and put.

Probably I understood something wrong: I used Beforeeach aimed to insert a register so I could check during get test. I don't get exception but it seems during get test it always returning ok when it should be NOT_FOUND for any other id different than 1 in bellow test.

Any clue or guidance in right direction will be wellcome even if see other bad practice bellow based on my purpose (simple CRUD test).

test

```
package com.mycomp.jokenpo

import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.mycomp.jokenpo.controller.UserController
import com.mycomp.jokenpo.model.User
import com.mycomp.jokenpo.respository.UserRepository
import com.mycomp.jokenpo.service.UserService
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.mockito.InjectMocks
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when`
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders


@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class JokenpoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var testRestTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mvc: MockMvc

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var controller: UserController

    @Mock
    lateinit var respository: UserRepository

    @Mock
    lateinit var service: UserService

    //private fun <T> any(type: Class<T>): T = Mockito.any<T>(type)

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).setMessageConverters(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()).build()
        `when`(respository.save(User(1, "Test")))
                .thenReturn(User(1, "Test"))

    }

    @Test
    fun createUser() {
        //val created = MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated

        var user = User(2, "Test")
        var jsonData = jacksonObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(user)
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/users/")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(jsonData))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)
                //.andExpect(created)
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andReturn()
    }

    @Test
    fun findUser() {

        val ok = MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk

        val builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/users?id=99") //no matther which id I type here it returns ok. I would expect only return for 1 based on my @BeforeEach
        this.mvc.perform(builder)
                .andExpect(ok)

    }
}
```

controller

```
package com.mycomp.jokenpo.controller

import com.mycomp.jokenpo.model.User
import com.mycomp.jokenpo.respository.UserRepository
import com.mycomp.jokenpo.service.UserService
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong
import javax.validation.Valid

@RestController
@RequestMapping("users")
class UserController (private val userService: UserService, private val userRepository: UserRepository){

    val counter = AtomicLong()

//    @GetMapping("/user")
//    fun getUser(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") name: String) =
//            User(counter.incrementAndGet(), "Hello, $name")

    @GetMapping()
    fun getAllUsers(): List<User> =
            userService.all()

    @PostMapping
    fun add(@Valid @RequestBody user: User): ResponseEntity<User> {
        //user.id?.let { userService.save(it) }
        val savedUser = userService.save(user)
        return ResponseEntity.ok(savedUser)
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    fun getUserById(@PathVariable(value = "id") userId: Long): ResponseEntity<User> {
        return userRepository.findById(userId).map { user ->
            ResponseEntity.ok(user)
        }.orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    fun deleteUserById(@PathVariable(value = "id") userId: Long): ResponseEntity<Void> {

        return userRepository.findById(userId).map { user  ->
            userRepository.deleteById(user.id)
            ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK)
        }.orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())

    }

//    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
//    fun deleteUserById(@PathVariable id: Long): ResponseEntity<Unit> {
//        if (noteService.existsById(id)) {
//            noteService.deleteById(id)
//            return ResponseEntity.ok().build()
//        }
//        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build()
//    }

    /////

//    @PutMapping("{id}")
//    fun alter(@PathVariable id: Long, @RequestBody user: User): ResponseEntity<User> {
//        return userRepository.findById(userId).map { user  ->
//            userRepository. deleteById(user.id)
//            ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK)
//        }.orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())
//    }

}
```

Repository

```
package com.mycomp.jokenpo.respository

import com.mycomp.jokenpo.model.User
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, Long>
```

Model

```
package com.mycomp.jokenpo.model

import javax.persistence.*


@Entity
data class User(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        val name: String
)
```

gradle dependencies

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.6.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.71"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.71"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.71"
}

group = "com.mycomp"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

val developmentOnly by configurations.creating
configurations {
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom(developmentOnly)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    //runtimeOnly("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation ("com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    platform: h2
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console #jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

In case it is usefull the whole project can be dowloaded from https://github.com/jimisdrpc/games but I am confident that all files above are enough to ilustrate my issue.

Comment: One idea: the get mapping uses repository.findByUserId() but you mock repository.save(). That doesn’t fit together.

Comment: @johanneslink, sorry I didn't get your point. In few words, I tried with above test before each test save an user {1, Test}  and during findUser test, with "... MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/users?id=99")..." I would expect the test fails and if I chence to "... MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/users?id=1") the test pass. Please, what issue you are trying to point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem I suggest using [@MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html), an annotation that can be used to add mocks to a Spring `ApplicationContext`.

I would re-write your test as follows (notice that I'm taking advantage of [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin#mockito-kotlin) already being a test dependency of your project):

```kotlin
package com.mycomp.jokenpo

import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.mycomp.jokenpo.model.User
import com.mycomp.jokenpo.respository.UserRepository
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.whenever
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.assertThrows
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.get
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.post
import org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException

@AutoConfigureMockMvc. // auto-magically configures and enables an instance of MockMvc
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
// Why configure Mockito manually when a JUnit 5 test extension already exists for that very purpose?
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class, MockitoExtension::class)
class JokenpoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @MockBean
    lateinit var respository: UserRepository

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        // use mockito-kotlin for a more idiomatic way of setting up your test expectations
        whenever(respository.save(User(1, "Test"))).thenAnswer {
            it.arguments.first()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `Test createUser in the happy path scenario`() {
        val user = User(1, "Test")
        mockMvc.post("/users/") {
            contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
            content = jacksonObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(user)
            accept = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
        }.andExpect {
            status { isOk }
            content { contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) }
            content { json("""{"id":1,"name":"Test"}""") }
        }
        verify(respository, times(1)).save(user)
    }

    @Test
    fun `Test negative scenario of createUser`() {
        val user = User(2, "Test")
        assertThrows<NestedServletException> {
            mockMvc.post("/users/") {
                contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
                content = jacksonObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(user)
                accept = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
            }
        }
        verify(respository, times(1)).save(user)
    }

    @Test
    fun findUser() {
        mockMvc.get("/users?id=99")
            .andExpect {
                status { isOk }
            }
        verify(respository, times(1)).findAll()
    }
}
```

Having said that, here's some food for thought:

- Any test needs to include verification to assert that the systems behaves as is expected under various types of scenarios including negative scenarios such as *how do we check if the service failed to create a new User record in the DB*.
- I noticed you already have a Test DB setup in your `ApplicationContext` (**H2**) so why not use it to create test records instead of just mocking the repository layer? Then you can verify the DB contains any newly created records.
- As a general rule, I avoid using *Mockito* with Kotlin tests (search StackOverflow for a couple of reasons why), or even [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin#mockito-kotlin). Best practice nowadays is to use the excellent [MockK](https://github.com/mockk/mockk) library in combination with either [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/) or [assertk](https://github.com/willowtreeapps/assertk) for verifying your expectations.

Comment: thanks, I will study MockK with AssertJ. Please, I didn't understand two points in answer: (1) why do you need "verify(respository)..."? You already   used "andExpect" for first and third test and "assertThrows" for second test. I understand you are  checking if the result is the expected or asserted. Aren't  "andExpect"  and "assertThrows"  for verification/? (2) In the third test, findUser, I was expecting only pass if it didn't find. That is the reason I search for 99. Why it returns "isOk"? I was expecting "isNotFound" (see the controller:  .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build()))

Comment: kindly, what does "verify(respository, times(1)).save(user)" add to my test? I remove it and it is still passing. I can see you try to help me warnning "Any test needs to include verification to assert" but I am certainlly missing some concept here.

Comment: Conceptually, unit tests that use mock objects include verification to check that the calls you setup actually did occur along with any expected inputs.If you can spare a few minutes of your day I suggest watching the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7_4WrImJPk

Comment: As for the third test, I added a verify statement to check that a call to your repository method `findAll` did in fact occur. The reason it succeeded is because your repository's mockito mock did in fact return a "nice" default value despite the fact that you did not set one up (counterintuitive perhaps?). I can assure you that the said behaviour, referred to as *relaxed mocks* is not default when using MockK. When using MockK, by default, *every expected call* must be setup and you can even force verification using `confirmVerified` (available since 1.9).

Answer (score 2):

To run get unit tests running in following setup:

```
 - Kotlin 
 - Spring Boot
 - JUnit 5
 - Mockito
 - Gradle
```

you need this configuration, to get started:

*build.gradle.kts*

```
dependencies {
   // ...

   testRuntimeOnly(group = "org.junit.jupiter", name = "junit-jupiter-engine", version = "5.6.3")
   testImplementation(group = "org.mockito", name = "mockito-all", version = "1.10.19")
   testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
       exclude(group = "org.junit.vin  tage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
   }

   // ...
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
   useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

*test file*

```
@org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
class YourTest {

    @org.mockito.Mock
    lateinit var testingRepo: TestingRepo

    @org.mockito.InjectMocks
    lateinit var testingService: TestingService


    @org.springframework.test.context.event.annotation.BeforeTestMethod
    fun initMocks() {
        org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    fun yourTest() {org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue(true)}

}
```