# What is the reason for an UninitializedPropertyAccessException in @SpringBootTest with MockK and Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, spring-boot-test, mockk

I am trying to use MockK 1.10.2 with Kotlin 1.4.10 and @SpringBootTest (Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE) and I can't get it run because of a

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot     loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
2020-11-05 15:00:37.878  WARN   --- [           main] i.m.p.j.t.InliningClassTransformer       : Failed to transform class java/lang/Object

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 59
at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:195)
at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176)
at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:162)
at net.bytebuddy.utility.OpenedClassReader.of(OpenedClassReader.java:86)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForInlining.create(TypeWriter.java:3394)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:1933)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.make(RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.java:217)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.make(AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.java:120)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3404)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.InliningClassTransformer.transform(InliningClassTransformer.kt:77)
at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:563)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:167)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.JvmInlineInstrumentation.retransform(JvmInlineInstrumentation.kt:28)
at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumnetation$execute$1.invoke(RetransformInlineInstrumnetation.kt:19)
at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumnetation$execute$1.invoke(RetransformInlineInstrumnetation.kt:6)
at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.ClassTransformationSpecMap.applyTransformation(ClassTransformationSpecMap.kt:41)
at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumnetation.execute(RetransformInlineInstrumnetation.kt:16)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.inline(ProxyMaker.kt:88)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.proxy(ProxyMaker.kt:30)

kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property taService has not been initialized
```

exception. (The same happens if I use tmpService. It doesn't matter if the imported service is in the same or a different package as the test class.)

As you can see from the code of my test class I already played around a lot but without any success so far.

```
package com.xxx.emr.tm

import com.xxx.data.emr.model.PatientAssignment
import com.xxx.data.tm.TMPService
import com.xxx.data.tm.model.MyType
import com.xxx.data.tm.model.MyTypeCode
import com.xxx.data.tm.model.UserAction
import com.xxx.emr.service.model.AuthenticatedUser
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.impl.annotations.InjectMockKs
import io.mockk.impl.annotations.SpyK
import io.mockk.junit5.MockKExtension
import io.mockk.mockk
import io.mockk.mockkObject
import io.mockk.verify
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest

 @ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class, MockKExtension::class)
 @SpringBootTest // (classes = [com.xxx.emr.service.MyServiceSpringBoot::class])
// @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)    
// @ActiveProfiles("test")
// @EnableAutoConfiguration
// @AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyTest {
// (
//    val tmpService: TMPService,
//    val taService: TaService
// )

//    @InjectMockKs
//    @Autowired
//    @SpyK
@MockK
private lateinit var tmpService: TMPService

@InjectMockKs
@Autowired
private lateinit var taService: TaService

@Test
fun assignAToB() {
    
    MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true)

    val vId = "xxx"
    val authUser: AuthenticatedUser = AuthenticatedUser.mockedUser()
    val userAction = UserAction(
        userId = "user_id",
        actionCode = ActionType.GET_IT,
        sessionId = "sessionId"
    )

    val xxx = MyType(
        MyTypeCode.ABC.value,
        MyTypeCode.ABC.name,
    )

    val actionResult = UserActionResult(hashMapOf("success" to true))

//        every { tmpService.getXxx(any()) } returns xxx

    verify( exactly = 1 ) {
        tmpService.doSomething(any(), any(), any())
    }

    verify( exactly = 1 ) {
         taService.dowhatYouWant(„vId", authUser, userAction)
    }
}
```

Autowiring does not work...so what is my fault? How can I make the test run at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should initialize your mocks first, by adding this in your test file for example:

```
@org.springframework.test.context.event.annotation.BeforeTestMethod
fun initMocks() {
    org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
}
```

I created a post on another thread about how to setup unit testing, comparable with your requirements:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64669499/7919904

Comment: I tried this without success. I do also have: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 59

Comment: Okay you are using MockK, I thought you were using Mockito... Maybe you should give Mockito a try?

Comment: Initialize mocks in MockK should be done this way, according to the MockK documentation:  MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true)

Comment: No success. Is MockK 1.10.2 not compatible with Java 15 (running on language level 11)? (Consider the very first lines of the exception's stack trace.)

Comment: Why using Java 15? 11 is the current LTS, 15 will never be LTS :)

Comment: I just installed the latest version. I thought, running on language level 11 would be the same is if installing Java 11. BTW: OpenJdk

Comment: I would recommend using Java 11, at least you can give it a try

Comment: I thought, running a higher Java version on the respective lang level would behave like Java of this level, but using OpenJdk-11, the mentioned exceptions are gone. (Now I have different ones. LOL)